# Need to style Div's with a border and some space between them

Tags: html, css

not good at styling...I want to give my div's that are in a loop that are "sortable" a kind of button look with a border and some space between them....any suggestions:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="shaded" style="padding: 0px;" align="center">
            <div id="sortable" style="border:1px solid black">
                <c:forEach var="field" items="${detFields}">
                    <div id="${field.fieldName}">${field.fieldName}</div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>   



$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `margin` should give them the space you need:

```
style="border:1px solid black; margin: 10px"
```

Comment: bout to try this mate....thanks for the reply